# Nokogiri: unable to screen scrape a page(taobao.com)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, screen-scraping, nokogiri

I'm using nokogiri to get images from a Chinese website(Taobao.com):

```
  url = "http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a1z10.1.w137644-1960500098.43.d7Uwpx&id=36246359192"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url) )
  puts doc.css("title").text
  puts doc.css("img")[0]['src']
  puts doc.css("img#J_ImgBooth")[0]['src']
```

I can get the title and `doc.css("img")[0]['src']`, but I am unable to get the `img#J_ImgBooth`. What is the problem? Is it blocked somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the html source, there is no src but data-src attribute of img#J_ImgBooth

```
<img id="J_ImgBooth" data-src="http://img03.taobaocdn.com/bao/uploaded/i3/18513032853503639/T1z1ojXdNhXXXXXXXX_!!2-item_pic.png_310x310.jpg"  data-hasZoom="700" />
```

use

```
doc.css("img#J_ImgBooth")[0]['data-src']
```

will be fine.

Comment: `<img id="J_ImgBooth" data-haszoom="700" data-src="http://img03.taobaocdn.com/bao/uploaded/i3/18513032853503639/T1z1ojXdNhXXXXXXXX_!!2-item_pic.png_460x460.jpg" src="http://img03.taobaocdn.com/bao/uploaded/i3/18513032853503639/T1z1ojXdNhXXXXXXXX_!!2-item_pic.png_460x460.jpg">`

Comment: That's what I see. There is a `src` attribute

Comment: Did you see this from the chrome's element inspector? It may be modified by the js when the page get loaded, it may not be the actual html code what Nokogiri is seeing.

Comment: This is from firebug. So how can I get the original html? or get the following passed by js?

Comment: use wget to get the original html file; or right click on the page and pick up the "view page source" menu item.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

`doc.at_css("#J_ImgBooth")["data-src"]`

You can check the attributes name is `data-src`:

```
#(Element:0x3ffb5d3d9df0 {
  name = "img",
  attributes = [
    #(Attr:0x3ffb5d3d9b84 { name = "id", value = "J_ImgBooth" }),
    #(Attr:0x3ffb5d3d9b70 {
      name = "data-src",
      value = "http://img03.taobaocdn.com/bao/uploaded/i3/18513032853503639/T1z1ojXdNhXXXXXXXX_!!2-item_pic.png_310x310.jpg"
      }),
    #(Attr:0x3ffb5d3d9b5c { name = "data-haszoom", value = "700" })]
  })
```